# Http/REST method for starting a service

Tags: http, rest

I want to design a REST API to start a database. I can't find a suitable http method (aka verb).

I currently consider:

```
START /databases/mysampledatabase
```

I've browsed through a few RFCs, but then I thought someone here might point me to a de-facto standard verb.

Methods I've discarded (before I got tired of looking):

**RFC 2616**
OPTIONS
GET
HEAD
POST
PUT
DELETE
TRACE
CONNECT

**RFC 2518**
PROPFIND
PROPPATCH
MKCOL
COPY
MOVE
LOCK
UNLOCK

**RFC 3253**
REPORT
CHECKOUT
CHECKIN
UNCHECKOUT
MKWORKSPACE
UPDATE
LABEL
MERGE
BASELINE-CONTROL
MKACTIVITY

Comment: I'm unclear what your criteria is.  You seem to have exhausted all of the officially sanctioned verbs.

Comment: I don't believe I have. Also, I'm looking to conform with other APIs, not necessarily to adhere to a W3C standard or a RFC/draft. I believe even the great PATCH method started out by usage before standardisation.

Comment: I've considered: START, EXECUTE, RUN

Comment: See http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2011-07-03-nobody-understands-rest-or-http, under the sub-heading **"A digression about actions".**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a bunch of thinking flaws here.. first off, the additional HTTP verbs (aside from the CRUD ones) should be considered not-restful.

So there's two ways I can interpret this question, and I have an answer for both:

**1. What's the most appropriate HTTP method for starting a service**

There's nothing quite like what you need, and I would advise simply using `POST`.

**2. What's a good RESTful way to start a service**

First, you should not see 'starting the service' as the action. It's easier to think of the 'status' (being started or stopped) as the resource you are changing, and PUT to update the resource.

So in this case, each service should have a unique uri. A `GET` on that uri could return something like :

```
{ "status" : "stopped" }
```

You just change 'stopped' to 'started', `PUT` the new resource.. and then the service could automatically begin running.

I wonder how useful this is though.. I'm not a REST zealot, and I think a simple POST is the best way to go.

**edit** I can't delete accepted answers, but since 2013 my thoughts on what is and isn't RESTful has nuanced quite a bit. I still think my example to represent the changable state of each service as a property still holds.